# Issue with sending data to PHP from jQuery .ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

Alright so I am using Yii and need to pass some data to the controller method called events and my jQuery ajax call looks like this

```
var objectToSend = { "categories" : [selectedOption],"datefrom" : month + "" + year , "dateto" : month + "" + year};



                $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('calendar/events'); ?>',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: objectToSend,

                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            console.log('failed');
                        }

                    });
```

So what I would like to do is send the data to the calendar/events , which would then be "catched" by events method, do some DB fetching and bring back data to the jQuery uppo success. Problem is that I always get error logged and the message (failed) to console when doing it. I get an empty string back from the controllers method, which is weird. I am just testing it out with simple code in it, looks like this

```
public function actionEvents()
    {

        $data = json_decode(Yii::app()->request->getPost('data'),true); // assoc array is returned if second param is true

        echo json_encode($data);
            Yii::app()->end();
    }
```

I am guessing the problem lies in data object sent to the method without data={ json data here }, but only as { json data here } without the "data=" part. What do you think? Is there a way I can "prefix" the data object send to PHP file with "data="somehow ?
I appreciate all the help

Comment: I guess you could use an array similar to the ones generated when serializing a form with JQuery so you can set the "data" name to the info you are sending. I would suggest using Firebug to check what are you exactly sending to the server tho.

Comment: On error, I get returned "null" when logging data.

Comment: POST sent to the method is "categories%5B%5D=test-category-for-events&datefrom=82013&dateto=82013"

Comment: `data: {data:objectToSend}` try this.

Comment: Ineersa thank you very much my friend ! :) That actualy works and the POST data finaly has a good setup and looks like " data {"categories":["test-category-for-events"],"datefrom":"82013","dateto":"82013"} "

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) say that $.ajax's data param "is converted to a query string". As a result, `json_decode`ing it is useless. If you want to send JSON data, you'll probably need to `JSON.stringify` your `objectToSend` first. If you do this, you should also set an appropriate Content-Type header.

Apparently Yii won't decode a JSON POST body by itself but according to [PR 2059](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/pull/2059) you can use either PHP's `json_decode` or Yii's version and get the POST body with `Yii::app()->request->getRawBody()`.

My guess is that you probably don't want to `json_decode` your data and just use the POST variables directly:

```
Yii::app()->request->getPost('categories');
```

Comment: After stringifying data sent I get POST looking like this 
"{"categories":["test-category-for-events"],"datefrom":"82013","dateto":"82013"}"